# What does '+' mean in network interfaces of iptables rules?

Tags: networking, iptables

I am running a customized Linux(kernel version 3.18.21) on MIPS 32. When I run `iptables -L -v`, it shows some rules like the following in the INPUT section:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 21 packets, 1816 bytes)
pkts bytes target   prot opt in     out     source       destination
0     0     DROP    tcp  --  !br+   any     anywhere     anywhere       tcp dpt:http
0     0     DROP    tcp  --  ppp+   any     anywhere     anywhere       multiport dports domain,3555,5555,49152,49153
```

Per my understanding, the `!` symbol before `br+` in the 'in' section means negative, which, in other words, suggests the rule excludes the network interface in this section. Am I right?

Another question is, what does `+` after the network interface `br` and `ppp` mean?

Answer (score 9):

It's kind of like a wildcard, matching any interface beginning with that prefix.  i.e. `ppp+` means any interface beginning with `ppp` (e.g. ppp0, ppp1, ppp2, ..., pppN), and `!br+` means any interface NOT beginning with `br`.

Answer (score 9):

According to the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables):

> When the "!" argument is used before the interface name, the sense is inverted. If the interface name ends in a "+", then any interface which begins with this name will match. If this option is omitted, any interface name will match.